# How can I debug Drools rule on IntelliJ?

Tags: java, drools

We have a legacy Java/Spring project which uses Drools rule. Is there any way to debug rules file on IntelliJ such as adding breakpoint and step through rule logic?

Answer (score 5):

What I do is defining a static method taking one param of type Object. This method can be later used as a debug callback. This way you can debug both LHS and RHS side of the rule:

```
class DroolsUtils {
  public static boolean debugLhsValue(Object value) {
    log.debug(value.toString()); // you can set breakpoint here
    return true;
  }
}
```

Than in your DRL file you can use it using following trick:

```
 import function com.bnymellon.ais.rei.dataexchange.brms.runtime.BrmsPluginHelper.debugLhsValue;


  rule "my rule"

  enabled true

  when
    $model : MyModel()
    MyModel(debugLhsValue($model) == true) from $model

    $mapInMyModel: Map() from $model.someMap; 
    MyModel(debugLhsValue($mapInMyModel) == true) from $model

    Entry(getKey() == "something", $myValue: getValue()) from $mapInMyModel.entrySet();
    MyModel(debugLhsValue($myValue) == true) from $model

  then
    debugLhsValue("in RHS");
    // do something 
  end
```

As shown above, you can call to this debug function after each instruction. You can also use it inside condition clauses. The only thing left is to set breakpoint inside your debugLhsValue and you know what the values are.

Comment: This is a bit tricky, especially when you work with a stateful session. If I change a value without modify or update, java will show me the correct result after set, while the engine will be unware. But overall I agree, it's a good debugging practise.

Answer (score 3):

Point of Toni is valid (Idea plugin does not allow debugging of the actual Drools rule) but be aware you can put breakpoints on the actual Java methods being invoked by the Drools role. Following code snippet will help a little (isRuleApplicable and getAttribute are the actual Java methods):

```
//salience allows to give rules a priority
rule "Number of adults in the family" salience 10
when
    // condition on eligible is required to avoid endless loop
    stbFact: Stb()
    eval(stbFact.getEligible() == null && stbFact.isRuleApplicable("Number of adults in the family") && stbFact.getAttribute("enh_000010", "1", "5"))
then
    System.out.println("[Number of adults in the family] Drools Rule has been satisfied (debug purposes)!!!");
    stbFact.setEligible(Boolean.TRUE);
    update( stbFact );
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The Drools project has a plugin for Eclipse that allows debugging, but as far as I know the one in Idea does not have this.